# How to use Jaeger with Helidon Microprofile

Tags: jaeger, helidon

I have created a Helidon Microprofile quickstart project from helidon.io get started while configuring with Jaeger I am unable to find the Trace in Jaeger UI below are the steps which I have followed:

1. Created project using

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false \
       -DarchetypeGroupId=io.helidon.archetypes \
       -DarchetypeArtifactId=helidon-quickstart-mp \
       -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.4 \
       -DgroupId=io.helidon.examples \
       -DartifactId=helidon-quickstart-mp \
       -Dpackage=io.helidon.examples.quickstart.mp
   ```
2. Updated `pom.xml` with Jaeger dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.helidon.tracing</groupId>
       <artifactId>helidon-tracing-jaeger</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jaegertracing</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaeger-client</artifactId>
       <version>0.32.0</version>
   </dependency>`
   ```
3. Updated GreetApplication

   ```
   @Traced
   @ApplicationScoped
   @ApplicationPath("/")
   public class GreetApplication extends Application {......}
   ```
4. Updated /helidon-quickstart-mp/src/main/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties

   ```
    #Jaeger properties
   tracing.service=mp
   ```
5. Executed mvn package and then `target>java -jar helidon-quickstart-mp.jar`
6. Now in my Jaeger UI I am unable to trace the running Service:

   [image: Jarger UI did not show Services]

So how can I configure Jaeger UI to my helidon Microprofile project?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: https://github.com/jobinesh/cloud-native-applications/tree/master/helidon-example-mp-jaeger. See if that helps you. If you are interested, see the details captured here: https://www.jobinesh.com/2020/04/tracing-api-calls-in-your-helidon.html